# Indian passport: date of birth proof for 67 year old mother without any documents

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, paperwork, applications

I  need to get a passport for my 67 year old mom.

While she has a Masters degree from a reputed university, the date of birth on her school leaving certificate has the format "she is 15 years, 8 months, and 18 days old as on 1st March 1965". The Regional Passport Office (RPO) rejected this document because the current documentation format requires the date of birth to be in "DD/MM/YYYY" format.

The affidavit Annexure A declares the candidate to be an illiterate which is false in her case. At her time there were no birth certificates.

Comment: Why don't you just use the Master's degree document? Also, does the school she left at 15 still exist?

Comment: The degrees do not record DOB. Also the RPO only accepts birth certificate, School Leaving Certificate or Affidavit.

Comment: Does the school still exist?

Comment: I would think this is best-addressed by a specialist inside India, but can you modify Annexure A to delete all references to illiteracy and state instead that while the applicant has a degree and is literate, the school-leaving certificate does not have the birthdate in the correct format?

Comment: I think what you can do is that make an Affidavit where date of birth is in "DD/MM/YYYY" format and mention that it has been calculated from the school leaving certificate.

Comment: Does she have an Aadhaar Card?

Comment: If there are no school records then this document must be used: http://nriinformation.com/No_birthcertificate_affidavit_AnnexureA.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Contact the school which issued her "school leaving certificate" and ask them to issue a new copy, with the accepted date format.

This assumes that the school still exists, but since you haven't responded to comments regarding this, I'll assume it does.

Comment: Please note that as of December 2016, Indian govt. has [amended the rules](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/PressRelease_PassportRule.pdf). Now a host of documents such as PAN, Adhaar, Driving License and Voter I-cards are valid proof of date of birth as long as they mention the DOB of the applicant